# I have an issue website displaying "CyberPanel Installed"

Tags: wordpress, web, vps, cyber-panel

i hope you can help me with this issue i have an issue on one of my websites hosted on a hostinger vps with cyberpanel , the website was already live with content (wordpress blog) , after couple of weeks i started to have an issue, when i visit the website i see this message :
"CyberPanel Installed

You have successfully installed CyberPanel, please remove this page and upload your website. :)"

as if it is empty, I contacted hostinger support couple of times, but they werent able to help me, so they asked me to check the cyberpanel community or stackoverflow community.

does anyone know what could be the solution here because i tested the files and the database, dns. all look good.

i checked files of the wordpress on the server (especially wp-config.php) i also checked the database and the database table wp_option. also files permissions and dns records and all looked well